# How to change plot marker of a subset of points when using matplotlib scatter function in python 3

Tags: python, python-3.x, matplotlib, plot, scatter

I have many custom 2d points objects, each having:

- coordinates x and y
- label 1° (integer between -1 and +inf): this will be represented in the markers' color (index of cmap)
- label 2° (integer in the range of [1 3]): I want this one to be represented in the marker type

The thing is that many points will share a label 1° value, but may differ in the label 2° one, and vice versa.

I tried extracting the points regarding the value of label 2° and plotting them separately, this way:

```py
pointsSubset1 = getPointsWithLabel2Value1()
pointsSubset2 = getPointsWithLabel2Value2()
pointsSubset3 = getPointsWithLabel2Value3()

# just assume x y and labels values are obtained correctly

plt.scatter(x1, y1, c=listOfLabels1ForSubset1, cmap="nipy_spectral", marker='s') # plotting pointsSubset1

plt.scatter(x2, y2, c=listOfLabels1ForSubset2, cmap="nipy_spectral", marker='.') # plotting pointsSubset2

plt.scatter(x3, y3, c=listOfLabels1ForSubset3, cmap="nipy_spectral", marker='<') # plotting pointsSubset3
```

I thought this would work, but it doesn't. The markers are set correctly but not the colors ...

Example ignoring x and y coordinates:

- subset1 =

  - point1:

    - label1: -1
    - label2: 1
- subset2 =

  - point2:

    - label1: 1
    - label2: 2

In this case, point1 from subset1 will have a different marker than point2 from subset2, but both will share the same color (black) because when both are plotted separately, although they have different label1 values, both will be mapped to the first color in the spectrum ....

I want colors indexes in cmap to match between subsets of points, and I don't think passing a custom array of colors is the solution bc the label 1 possible values are in the range of [-1, +inf] (and I don't know how to manage cmap normalization).

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think would get to where you want

```
Npoints = 50
x,y = np.random.random(size=(2,Npoints))
label1 = np.random.choice([-1,1,2,3], size=(Npoints,))
label2 = np.random.choice([1,2,3],size=(Npoints,))

label1_min = min(label1)
label1_max = max(label1)
marker_dict = {1:'s',2:'o',3:'<'}

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
for i,m in marker_dict.items():
    ax.scatter(x[label2==i], y[label2==i], marker=m, c=label1[label2==i], cmap='nipy_spectral', vmin=label1_min, vmax=label1_max)
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

**The easy way:**

I will share what I found just in case anyone is struggling with the same issue. It turns out that you can call plt.scatter() once and provide an array of custom sizes for the markers. This way, you can 'play' changing the marker size according to a given criteria (label 2 value in my case), being able to see the difference between subsets of points when plotting.

It would be something like this:

```py
s = getMarkerCustomSizeForEachPoint()
# x is a list of every x coordinate
# y is a list of every y coordinate
# clusters is a list of every point label (label 1 value in my case)
# marker='s' -> squares
plt.scatter(x, y, c=clusters, cmap="nipy_spectral", marker='s', alpha=0.8, s=s)
```

Setting the marker size to a really small number, it's almost like having points, so you can use squares and 'points' while you only specify marker='s' :)

Remember when building the different lists that indexes that match represent the same point (in x, y, clusters, and s)

[image]